# Axes in matplotlib are doubling up, and I can only get rid of one set

Tags: python, matplotlib

*I searched for similar questions, but couldn't find anything that looks quite like this matplotlib double-ticks problem.*

*Also I read through the matplotlib documentation for subplots and axes, but can't find where the "second set" of axis ticks are coming from.  See below.*

---

This code generates three random histograms as subplots.  Note the `.set_visible(False)` calls on the x-axis and y-axis for each subplot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey = True, squeeze = True)
for index in range(0, 3):
    ax[index] = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, index + 1)
    ax[index].hist(np.random.normal(size=100))

    ax[index].get_yaxis().set_visible(False) # <-- trying to hide the axis ticks.
    ax[index].get_xaxis().set_visible(False) # <-- trying to hide the axis ticks.

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

It renders like this.  Notice that, despite trying to hide the axes, they're still there.  Also they range from 0 to 1 on both X and Y, which doesn't reflect the underlying data.

<kbd>[image: single axis ticks]</kbd>

And when I omit the axis-hiding calls with code like this.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey = True, squeeze = True)
for index in range(0, 3):
    ax[index] = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, index + 1)
    ax[index].hist(np.random.normal(size=100))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

It renders with two sets of axes on all x-axes, and on the leftmost y-axis.  The other covers the range of the actual data.

<kbd>[image: doubled up axis ticks]</kbd>

Can anyone point out my mistake here?  I only want the axis ticks that actually reflect the data, and ideally they would all share a y-axis.

Comment: You are creating two sets of subplots (each with 3 subplots). You need to decide if you want to create your subplots via `plt.subplots` or via `fig.add_subplot`.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  That fixed it.  If you make that an answer I'll accept it.  Also, can you suggest any book, blog series, or any other resource to help matplotlib feel a bit more natural?  I'm an experienced developer, but I'm finding it much more difficult to get fluent with matplotlib than other libraries.

Comment: I can recommend the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org). It contains (mostly) complete API docstrings, tutorials and more than 800 examples of usage.